# CSSで要素内のテキストを上下左右の中央揃えにしたい

Tags: html, css

下図のように、`div`要素内のテキストを上下左右の中央揃えにしたいです。
どのようなCSSを書けば良いのでしょうか？
[image: 上下左右の中央揃え]
`width:200px; height:200px;`と書いたのは一例です。
特にこの大きさ自体に意味があるわけではありませんが、要素の大きさはCSSで指定したいのです。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`display: table-cell`でできます。

```css
div.center {
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #88dd88;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">text center</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

中のテキストを`inline-block`にしたら、下記のように`text-align`が使えるようになります：

```
#outerdiv {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#centeredtext {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

divを親要素、pを子要素として、CSSを以下のように記述すると、
親要素の大きさに関係なく上下左右の中央になるのでは。

```
div p {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

ここらが参考になると思います。
http://coliss.com/articles/build-websites/operation/css/css-vertical-align-anything-by-sebastian.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; line-height: 200px">
      centered text
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

line-height指定でどうでしょうか。